# If statement: what is the difference

Tags: r, if-statement

What is the difference between:

```
if (beweg[temp+x,2] > 10 & x<0 | x>0)
```

and

```
if (beweg[temp+x,2] > 10 & x!=0)
```

I want to test whether `x` is not 0. Both give me difference solutions.

Comment: Look at booleans operators priorities; what about `if (beweg[temp+x,2]>10 & (x<0 | x>0))` . Also, next time, put an example of data and format code.

Comment: As pointed out by @EricLecoutre this is a matter of operator precedence. See `?Syntax` for details.

Comment: @ArunSharma R doesn’t have bitwise operators. `|` and `&` are vectorised conditional operators.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are bitwise operators in R, but they are different: `bitwAnd(a,b)` etc.

Comment: @RHertel That’s not an *operator*.